# Is there any way to avoid re-buffering on seeking backwards on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

When I seek back, say, a minute in a YouTube video, the player begins to buffer the video again. Is there any way to avoid this, by means of addons or userscripts and make it just keep the buffered content like it earlier used to?